# How to decompose a relationship collection in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm working with two tables. One called transacciones and another called transaction_details
This is the transacciones table

```
Schema::create('transacciones', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('modulo');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

This is the transaction_details table

```
Schema::create('transaction_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('transacciones_id')->unsigned();

        $table->string('accion');
        $table->string('variable');
        $table->string('anterior')->nullable();
        $table->string('nuevo')->nullable();

        $table->foreign('transacciones_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('transacciones')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I am trying to pass data to view using the following code in the controller file:

```
public function Transactions()
    {
        $logs = Transacciones::with('details')->get();
        return view('transacciones', compact('logs'));
    }
```

In the model file

```
@foreach($logs as $key => $log)

<tr>
    <td>{{ $log->id }}</td> //-> Works well

    <td>{{$log->details->accion}}</td> ->It doesn't work
    <td>{{$log->details->variable}}</td> ->It doesn't work
    <td>{{$log->details->anterior}}</td> ->It doesn't work
    <td>{{$log->details->nuevo}}</td> ->It doesn't work

    <td>{{ucfirst( $log->modulo) }}</td> //-> Works well
</tr>
@endforeach
```

In this case when trying to print returns the error: ***Property [accion] does not exist on this collection instance.***

I know this error is because **details is a collection**. So it doesn't get the action parameter and all the rest.
I understand this is resolved by doing a `foreach to $logs->details as $detail` But this would deform my whole board and look like this
[Deformed table by nested foreach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvQko.png)

Is it possible to do all this with just one foreach as in the Laravel documentation?
Let's leave something like this

```
<td>{{$log->details->accion}}</td>
<td>{{$log->details->varialbe}}</td>
<td>{{$log->details->anterior}}</td>
<td>{{$log->details->nuevo}}</td>
```

I'm new to Laravel. I've only been using it for a short time. I hope you can help me with this the truth is that I have more than 24 hours with the same problem and do not know how to solve it.

Edit:
Added dd($logs)

```
Collection {#1075 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => Transacciones {#913 ▶}
    1 => Transacciones {#914 ▼
      #table: "transacciones"
      #fillable: array:2 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:4 [▼
        "id" => 2
        "modulo" => "Usuarios"
        "created_at" => "2018-11-24 05:53:19"
        "updated_at" => "2018-11-24 05:53:19"
      ]
      #original: array:4 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "details" => Collection {#1072 ▼
          #items: array:6 [▼
            0 => Transaction_Detail {#1043 ▼
              #table: "transaction_details"
              #fillable: array:4 [▶]
              #connection: "mysql"
              #primaryKey: "id"
              #keyType: "int"
              +incrementing: true
              #with: []
              #withCount: []
              #perPage: 15
              +exists: true
              +wasRecentlyCreated: false
              #attributes: array:7 [▼
                "transacciones_id" => 2
                "accion" => "<Escribir>"
                "variable" => "nombres"
                "anterior" => "Joaquin Moises"
                "nuevo" => "Isaac Rosalind"
                "created_at" => "2018-11-24 05:53:19"
                "updated_at" => "2018-11-24 05:53:19"
              ]
              #original: array:7 [▶]
              #changes: []
              #casts: []
              #dates: []
              #dateFormat: null
              #appends: []
              #dispatchesEvents: []
              #observables: []
              #relations: []
              #touches: []
              +timestamps: true
              #hidden: []
              #visible: []
              #guarded: array:1 [▶]
            }
            1 => Transaction_Detail {#1044 ▶}
            2 => Transaction_Detail {#1045 ▶}
            3 => Transaction_Detail {#1046 ▶}
            4 => Transaction_Detail {#1047 ▶}
            5 => Transaction_Detail {#1048 ▶}
          ]
        }
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    2 => Transacciones {#915 ▶}
    3 => Transacciones {#916 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show the output for `dd($logs);` in your controller?

Comment: That's a view, not a model..

Comment: I edited to add the log

Answer (score 0):

I think you have defined one to many relationship so you have to loop again to display all of them. Are you sure this is the relationship you want and not the one to one?
Take a look at laravel docs for the relationships.
[laravel relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)

Also you have a typo here
`<td>{{$log->details->varialbe}}</td> ->It doesn't work`
it is variable as you specified it in your migration
`$table->string('variable');`

Comment: This is the relationship I want because a transaction has many details (transaction_details) hasMany().

With regard to the writing error I had already corrected it but that was not the problem.

Comment: Do you want to display only the latest one or all of them?

Comment: I need to show them all. All transactions with all their details  I managed to do this, but it's only 1 transaction. http://prntscr.com/lmjwb9

Comment: Take a look here man. It has several helper methods. Maybe each or all method will help you. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-collections. Try to concatenate the results and display them to one line if you wish. For example, test1,test2,test3 . I can't find an another way to display them all in the same td without breaking the table structure.